# How do pause code while waiting on feedback from sound_play?

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a little voice-recognition project going for myself where the system communicates through a listening node and a speaking node. The problem is that I can't figure out how to "pause" my code and wait for my speaking node to call on `.say()` in `sound_play` and finish speaking before my code can continue. Because as it is right it calls the .say() method and says what it's supposed to but the code just keeps on running ( listening ) while it's still saying it and I don't want that.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259243/how-do-pause-code-while-waiting-on-feedback-from-sound_play?/) by [Azul](https://answers.ros.org/users/30021/azul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've never used it, but from looking at the [source](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/sound_play/html/libsoundplay_8py_source.html#l00157), you can tell it to block:

> Each say/play/start/repeat method can
> take in an optional
> `blocking=True|False` argument that
> will over-ride the class-wide
> behavior. See soundclient_example.py
> for an example of this behavior.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Azul](https://answers.ros.org/users/30021/azul/) on 2017-04-15**:
Hi, my code is written in C/C++ and I'm not really sure how I could use this blocking function. Passing `blocking=true` to `sound_play::SoundClient.say()` doesn't seem to do the trick, it gives me a compile error that basically says I shouldn't pass that argument.